# How to sign a transaction object from within a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I am going to call an API via chainlink that returns a transaction object. Is it possible to then sign or send that object from within a smart contract?

So the user would sign an initial transaction that gives a smart contract permission to retrieve data for another transaction and send that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink AnyApi is used to fetch data from off-chain API. If you want to add access control of off-chain data source, you can create some credential or have an IP white list for API consumers.

Signature on a transaction can be used to verify that the tx is signed by an address or not but it is usually used on-chain behaviors. You don't need to use signature for off-chain data control access.

Hope it helps